# Компьютер не понимает пути по #include

Tags: include, пути, c++

Проблема такая, он не понимает когда так:

```
#include <здеся/тута/вотетот.h>
```

ему нужно чтобы было так:

```
#include <вотетот.h>
```

И из за этого мне нужно переписывать все .h в библиотеке, и кидать их в 1 папку. Ребят, это безумие, помогите исправить трабл.

Comment: @Markus  Lolovis смею заявить, что компьютер не тупой. Почитайте про различия синтаксиса "" и <>

Comment: я думаю, там ещё и компилятор не очень податливый:)

Comment: Спасибо, хоть какие-то ответы)
Про "" я думал, но поверьте писал двиг не я.

Comment: Скорее всего, Вам просто нужно правильно прописать каталоги с include. Но как именно их прописывать - зависит от компилятора и среды/оси.

Comment: @Markus  Lolovis, к сожалению напрочь не помню, как настроить компилятор (в принципе это возможно).


На практике (в Linux) можете поместить свои файлы (вместе с структурой каталогов) в `/usr/local/include` и gcc будет их нормально подтягивать.

Просто `/usr/local/include` это один из стандартных каталогов, в которых ищутся файлы, подключаемые в `<>`.

Comment: > На практике (в Linux) можете поместить свои файлы (вместе с структурой каталогов) в /usr/local/include

Зоопарк хедеров из разных проектов в одной папке - это ЗЕБЕСТ.

Comment: Вы представьте, мне нужно перепивывать всю либу, переписал Box2D.h, скинул все .h и .cpp в 1 папку, и теперь мне еще нужно править 91 файл из за этого.
Когда у моего товарища все нормально работает)
Компилер читает путь как название файла.

Comment: @Flammable, а если по другому не получается, то что делать? 

Можно, конечно, перечислить *все корневые каталоги проекта* с файлами .h в `-I` опциях компилятора в Makefile.

--

А в принципе, `/usr/local` это (IMHO) как раз правильное место для размещения всех нестанданртных проектов на данной машине.

Comment: > а если по другому не получается, то что делать?

Пути поиска хедеров элементарно конфигурируются. Если проблемы возникают уже здесь - выкинуть руки, наверное.

Comment: @Flammable, если это элементарно, то напишите, как сделать (только не надо отсылать в гугл или к чтению страниц документации).

Просто пяток строчек, где и что конкретно прописать.

Comment: > напишите, как сделать

ТС не указал, какой средой он пользуется, а ясновидение я еще не освоил.
Если Visual Studio - Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories
Если Eclipse - Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols

> А в принципе, /usr/local это (IMHO) как раз правильное место для размещения всех нестанданртных проектов

То есть после git clone вы руками выдираете хедеры из своего репозитория и складываете их в /usr/local? И перед каждым коммитом возвращаете все на место? Любопытный подход.

Comment: А причем здесь `git` и вообще совместная разработка?

Comment: Какую среду, какой компилятор используешь?

Comment: > А причем здесь git и вообще совместная разработка?

to @avp
Действительно, причем здесь совместная разработка?
А git притом, что ни один нормальный девелопер не пишет сколь-либо серьезные проекты без контроля версий. И ваш любопытный подход с пиханием всех хедеров в /usr/local, мягко говоря, не слишком совместим с процессом разработки.

Comment: @Markus: Вы бы и правда указали ваш компилятор и среду. И привели бы конкретный пример: где лежат header'ы библиотек, где ваш проект, с какими ключами (настройками проекта) компилируете и т. д.

Comment: Как развернуть дискуссию за практики программирования на ровном месте